# Is there a way to have one line of ksh specific code inside of a bash file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ksh

I'm trying to use an associative array inside of a bash file. But the bash version is not 4.

Or is there a way to include a ksh file into a bash file without it executing as bash

Comment: bash is not ksh, but -- what exactly are you trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i want to use an associative array but inside of a bash file. the problem is my bash is not updated to version 4 yet so associative arrays are not supported. But I can use associative arrays in a ksh file. I want to be able to identify a line as ksh within a bash file.

Comment: `ksh -c /path/to/ksh.script` - but are you hoping to trick bash into understanding ksh's associative array somehow?

Comment: pretty much if thats possible

Comment: Why don't you just write a ksh script instead of a bash script? Right tool for the job, and all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can try this sort of things :

```
#!/bin/bash

ksh -c '
typeset -A arr
arr['foo']=1
arr['bar']=2
arr['base']=3
print "${arr[@]}"'
```

#### Or using a *here-doc*

```
#!/bin/bash

ksh <<'EOF'
typeset -A arr
arr['foo']=1
arr['bar']=2
arr['base']=3
print "${arr[@]}"
EOF
```

#### Disclaimer

As stated by @[glenn jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman) in the comments, the best you can do is to fully make your script in pure [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh), why bother you with a mix of [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) & [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) ?

#### Output

```
3 2 1
```

Answer (score -1):

No. That are different programs. You only may call ksh with parameter `-c` and e.g. parse the output.